# RoR application design for real estate web site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to implement a real estate app. But i'm stuck at designing models associations. I's  my first RoR app.

**Situation**

The app has different types of properties/estate(house, apartment, garage, land etc). These properties have some common attributes(name, price, description) and some specific ones for different types of property. But those specific ones can be common for some types.

**Problem**

I need to implement CRUD actions on these. And some search form with filters. Basically, all standard stuff for a Real Estate web site.

**p.s.** Sorry for my english. I hope you'll understand what i meant:)

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us to design this?

Comment: No. I'm asking for some suggestions. May be some basic structure.

Comment: @Tankard - Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's usual to post your first thoughts here, and then ask for feedback.

Comment: You might have a look at polymorphic relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a group of models with common attributes, one solution is to implement the models using Single Table Inheritance.  What this means is that you define a single database table that has the columns to support any of the models and their variants.  Your database table might have common columns for price, description, and name, but it would also include a square footage column that would never be used for land (but which might be used for both a condo and a house).  You'd have an additional column ('type' by default) in your table that would designate the type of each record.

More here: [ActiveRecord documentation has a section on STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is now an open source ROR real estate website builder you can learn from:

https://github.com/etewiah/property_web_builder